# Shock-waves, Bangs and the Speed of Sound

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, acoustics, shock-waves

I was watching  [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUREX8aFbMs) video of an erupting volcano. Some Guys in the comments tried to estimate how far away the volcano is by using the delay until the "shock-wave" hits the camera and the speed of sound in air. However, shock-waves can travel much faster than the speed of sound.

Is there a way to tell (or estimate) if what we are hearing is actually (still) a shock-wave? From [this](http://www.acoustics.asn.au/journal/2013/2013_41_2_Fletcher_paper.pdf) paper on hand clapping and shock-waves I conclude, that not all "bangs" need to be caused by shock-waves. And shock-waves can be only very shortly lasting, especially if there is not much energy involved.

And is the result viable when we calculate the distance in the way described above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual shock wave is quite short lived (I think it's visible for less than a second near 0:14 as a white sheet around the smoke/dust cloud) and doesn't propagate very far in this case. When the shock dissipates what's left is a pressure wave, the "bang" or sonic boom, and that propagates at the speed of sound.

So I guess your video uses a reasonable method, but sloppy terminology.